# Get data listed in rows to sit in columns

Tags: excel

I have exported a list of items from a website, this data all sits in row one with different 'types' of data in every 8th row.

For example The name of the first item item is in row 1, with its date in row 2 and a barcode in row 3 etc
The second product name is in row 8 with its corresponding date in row 9 and its barcode in row 10 etc

I would like to rearrange this into columns so that every 8th row goes into a column.  Does anyone know how to do this please?

I have tried transposing the data but this does not work.

See the current data format from my sheet below:

[image: current data format:]
The format I would like is as below:

[image: format required:]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `INDIRECT` and `ADDRESS` functions:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(COLUMN(A1)+(7*(ROW(A2)-2)) - COLUMN($A$1) + ROW($A$1); ROW(A$1) - ROW($A$1) + COLUMN($A$1)))
```

[image]